# Visual Studio Code 0.2.0 and opening .snl project

Tags: c#, csproj, visual-studio-code

I have been using Visual Studio Code a little bit with some experimental Unity3D projects. Now I got an insiders email about the 0.2.0 update and decided to give it a go. After the update VSCode start up nicely, butit runs into errors when trying to open a .csproj file.

This is my error log

```
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem] Loading project from '/Users/username/Projects/NewSmallGame/NewSmallGame/Assembly-CSharp-vs.csproj'.
[WARNING:OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem] Failed to process project file '/Users/username/Projects/NewSmallGame/NewSmallGame/Assembly-CSharp-vs.csproj'.
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.BuildProperty].get_Item (System.String key) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Create (OmniSharp.Options.MSBuildOptions options, ILogger logger, System.String solutionDirectory, System.String projectFilePath, ICollection`1 diagnostics) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem.CreateProject (System.String projectFilePath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
/Users/username/Projects/NewSmallGame/NewSmallGame/Assembly-CSharp-vs.csproj(0,0)
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.BuildProperty].get_Item (System.String key) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Create (OmniSharp.Options.MSBuildOptions options, ILogger logger, System.String solutionDirectory, System.String projectFilePath, ICollection`1 diagnostics) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem.CreateProject (System.String projectFilePath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

And this is not in any way restricted to Unity projects, but happens with all projects. I tried one generated with MonoDevelop and one made with Visual Studio 2010 that I downloaded.

What could be the cause of this error? It seems, that VSCode cant find a single character from the file since it refers to

```
/Assembly-CSharp-vs.csproj(0,0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what caused the error on leading the projects, but it seems to have been fixed in the new 0.3.0 release.